# Is it possible to use argparse but pass in a custom argv instead of it using sys.argv?

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to pass in a custom list of arguments?

More out of curiosity vs. a real life use case, but for example, I might want to convert all parameters to lowercase before having argparse do its job.

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments). Just pass in the list you want to `parse_args`.

From the example in the documentation:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--sum', '7', '-1', '42'])
Namespace(accumulate=<built-in function sum>, integers=[7, -1, 42])
```

Answer (score 1):

`parse_args` uses `sys.argv[1:]` if you don't give it a list argument. You can load `sys.argv` yourself, and modify it.  If modified in-place it can still be passed implicitily.

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = ...

# modify sys.argv inplace
sys.argv[1:] = [x.lower() for x in sys.argv[1:]]
args = parser.parse_args()  # pass it implicitily
# or pass it explicitly
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```